# How is a shot like this done? (Smooth angle shift in extreme slow-motion)

Tags: slowmotion

https://i.imgur.com/LqzejN9.mp4

How is this achieved? It seems like the camera would have to go from sitting still to moving extremely fast to capture a pan that far to the side while the wave is moving in such incredibly slow motion. Right? If the camera was changing angle at non-insane speeds, its angle change would happen in extreme slow motion just like the environment it seems like to me.

But it's over water in the waves, so it could be a drone but can drones really go from hovering still to instantly moving as fast as necessary for that shot? They could have a boat with a rig to pull the camera sideways fast but it would have to be pretty close considering the angle change and wouldn't it have problems because the waves are bouncing it around?

Comment: It might be that, Michael, but it actually looks from some of the morphing that it might be all in the edit rather than multiple cameras. Look at the leading edge of the wave as it goes past the surfer - I think the foreground and background are taken from the video, while the surfer is frozen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to agree with @Michael on this one, Bullet Time (as the name suggests when opening up the image "Surfing Bullet Time" would probably be the best result. To be fair it was probably filmed on a small boat (cameras in waterproof housings) as take just as the boat goes over the wave (just before it turns over)

Here is the actual video

It was shot with 12 GoPro cameras